# MFC CListCtrl groups in Icon view

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

Is it possible to group items in `CListCtrl` with `Icons` view?

I know how to do it with `Report` view, and complited solution presented on CodeProject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29354/CListCtrl-and-Grouping-Rows
[image]

I played with this example and it doesn't work with another styles of view.
But I need something that looks like this:

[image: CListCtrl Icons with grouping]

Is there a way to do it in MFC? Maybe some free existing 3rd-party control?

Comment: [Grouping is available in all views except list view. It is not available on controls that have the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#arranging-list-items-by-group)

Comment: Yes, this documentation help me understand what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is. I have done it in the past.